# OOPS design for the table relationship

Tags: c#, oop

For the below table design, i have designed the class as follows to perform the Get and Set operations on the DataItem table.

[image]

In order to perform the required CRUD operations on the table, I have defined the class and methods as follows,

```
public enum DataType
{
    Cards = 1,
    Activation = 2,
    Super = 3
}

public enum DataStatus
{
    ToBeProcessed = 1,
    Processed = 2,
    Failed = 3
}

public class CommonDataItem
{
    public int DataItemID { get; set; }
    public DataType DType { get; set; }
    public DataStatus DStatus { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateInserted { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
}

public GetDataItems(DataType dType, DataStatus dStatus)
{

}

public SetDataItems() { }
```

Basically the DataItem table holds the different JSON data for different data types as marked in the snapshot.

I need to create a generic class so that irrespective of the data types added in future, this class should perform its operations.

Please let me know if this is the right way to design the class structure or is there a better way to do the way via Interface and others.

Comment: Why store different type of data in a single table?

Comment: Yeahh agreed. But currently, i cannot change the way the DB has been structured. Need to write a service on this data. For which i need to know if i should be doing anything else for a better design to start with